# scss compiles successfully with laravel-mix but doesnt change in the browser

Tags: css, laravel, sass, laravel-blade

I have seen many other posts with a similar issues but none solved my problem. I am working on a laravel 6 application and I am adding css in my app.scss code which compiles into app.css. When I run `npm run dev` laravel mix compiles successfully and I refresh my browser and.... no changes to my actual css. I am only changing some font-sizes, colors nothing fancy.
Any help is appreciated.

List of commands I have tried:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dumpautoload
npm run dev
npm run watch
npm run watch-poll
ctrl+f5
ctrl+shift+r
-I inspected the page, found the actual css file in the browser and hard refreshed it.
-I opened the same project in an incognito window
-I tried chrome and firefox and incognito window 
-I updated my version of laravel-mix
```

None of these commands worked and now I am out of ideas.

blade file I am targeting

```
<div class="media">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column .vote-controls">
                                <a title="This question is useful" class="vote-up">
                                    <i class="fas fa-caret-up fa-3x"></i>
                                </a>
                                <span class="votes-count">1234</span>
                                <a title="This question is not useful" class="vote-down off">
                                    <i class="fas fa-caret-down fa-3x"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a title="Click to mark as favorite question (click again to undo)" class="favorite">
                                    <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
                                    <span class="favorites-count">1234</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
```

CSS in app.scss

```
.vote-controls {
        min-width: 60px;
        margin-right: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        color: $gray-700;

        span, a {
            display: block;
        }

        span {
            &.votes-count {
                font-size: 25px;
            }

            &.favorites-count {
                font-size: 12px;
            }
        }

        a {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: $gray-600;

            &.off, &.off:hover {
                color: $gray-500;
            }

            &.favorite {
                &.favorited, &.favorited:hover {
                    color: $warning;
                }
            }

            &.vote-accepted {
                color: $green;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this same issue by hard refreshing my browsers (cmd+shift+r). In the case of Firefox, I had to close the developer console and hard refresh in order to finally see the changes. I gave this a try after viewing my page with Safari and seeing the style changes I had made. Safari mustn't have had the resources cached the same way as Firefox or Chrome.